# -bash: git@github.com:rekiiel/forwardemail.net.git: No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-23.10

i try to install [Forwardemail](https://github.com/forwardemail/forwardemail.net) on my raspberry pi 4 with ubuntu server 23.10 64bit, so I followed the instructions but at step 5

```
git@github.com:forwardemail/forwardemail.net.git
cd forwardemail.net
```

I have this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdVUi.png)

Can someone help me, I don't know enough to find the solution myself.
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands should instead be:

```
git clone git@github.com:forwardemail/forwardemail.net.git
cd forwardemail.net
```